# Suspension fork top caps

Tags: fork, suspension

I bought second-hand mountain type bike. Everything is fine, however, front suspension fork is missing top caps. [image: Detail on missing cap]

As I currently don't posses the chance to visit bike repair shop (and have no other suspension fork equipped bike to compare available), I would like to ask, what do I need to replace. The fork is probably manufactured by Olpran (no other marks found) and I assume there was no option to regulate dampening force*

While looking for term "suspension fork caps" on the internet I found several replacements, however, they all seem to be mounted on some kind of valve (like this, image from ebay) [image: Cap replacement found on ebay]

**Thank you very much in advance!**

- Disclaimer: I am total amateur with minimal knowledge about bicycles, however very interested.

Comment: If you could provide us with the type of fork you have (or bike if fork is standard) We would need to know what technology you are using.

Comment: I think the OP has a cheap department store bicycle (also called [BSO]). The suspension is a simple spring with no dampeners. In those cases, the cap is simply there to prevent water from getting in. You could replace with a champagne cork (trimmed to fit) or duct tape.

Comment: The top cap on most forks holds the internals in place.  The photo shows missing internals. If the fork appears to be working its probably got a spring but no dampener (often spring is one side and dampener the other, but cheap forks can have a spring both sides.) Whats the other side like?

Comment: Caps shown are for Air forks -effectively they are a fancy schrader valve cap.

Comment: I'd just tape over the holes with duct tape, to keep rain and dirt out.  A blob of RTV silicon might do fine too.  Your last image shows a bike with suspension lockout, far more complex and expensive than what you ahve.

Comment: @mattnz the other side is visually exactly the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Michal,  I can't be certain from your picture, but your fork looks a lot like mine.  If it's the same kind of design, then the caps are simply plastic plugs, not threaded, simply friction-fit into the openings.

Here's a picture of the cap area of my fork.

[image]

If mine were missing I'd do just what @RoboKaren said, either make a plug out of a genuine cork champagne cork or maybe one of the plastic ones or (probably what I'd do) just duct tape over the area after cleaning the area with soapy water then mineral spirits to remove all surface contaminants and make sure the tape sticks.  You can get black duct tape if you want it to blend in.

BTW I'm assuming my suspension fork uses elastomer "springs" for the shock-absorbing effect, but I'm not positive because I've never been inside.

Comment: Thank you, it really seems to be this design. Mine "tubes" are also thread-less and from top they seem to be hollow.